# Can I insert a Button along with progress bar into RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to insert a Button along with progress bar into RichTextBox and when user click on that button then some things will happen.
Many chat apps has file transfer utility. user just drag the file onto RichTextBox then a progress bar shown along with accept button on the other end. I am developing chat apps and I want that when any user drag any file on my RichTextBox in my win chat apps then a progress bar and button will display in same line on RichTextBox. I search google but found no hint.
So anyone help me with concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, with difficulty: There is an article describing the process http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12135/Inserting-images-into-a-RichTextBox-control-the-OL

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9151/LinkTextBox-a-quick-solution-for-entering-emails-a